# Apache Error After Upgrade: Cannot load module mod_ssl.so: undefined symbol: SSL_get_srp_userinfo"

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, ssl

After I upgrade the Apache to version 2.4.12, its giving error at the time of start. I used below commands to install apache.

```
   ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/apache2 --enable-so --enable-ssl --enable-mod_shared=all
make clean all
make
make install
```

I replaced the new httpd.conf with my old httpd.conf and now While starting apache, I get below error.

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 148 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_ssl.so into server: /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so: undefined symbol: SSL_get_srp_userinfo
```

Can anyone tell if I am missing anything and how to resolve it now.

Answer (score 1):

> httpd: Syntax error on line 148 of /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load modules/mod_ssl.so into server: /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_ssl.so: undefined symbol: SSL_get_srp_userinfo

`SSL_get_srp_userinfo` is part of `libssl` (and not `libcrypto`), presuming you did not `Configure` with `no-srp`:

```
$ nm ./libSSL.dylib | grep SSL_get_srp_userinfo
0000000000038830 T _SSL_get_srp_userinfo
```

So it sounds like your problem is with your `mod_ssl.so` or `libssl.so`. You should ensure `libssl.so` includes SRP, and you should ensure `mod_ssl.so` uses a version of `libssl` that includes SRP.